# Dynamically generated buttons with onClick event attached

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom-events

I have problems with attaching `onclick` event at HTML5 button. I'm trying to generate row of buttons dynamically, based on parameter:

```
    var buttons: { 
      'Save': () => console.log('Save'),
      'Edit': () => console.log('Edit'),
    };
```

And generation process:

```
private getButtons(): string {
  let buttons: string = '';
  Object.entries(this.buttons).map(([key, value]: [string, () => any]) => {
    buttons += ` <button onclick="${value}">${key}</button>`
  });

  return buttons;
}
```

I've tried many ways of adding this function as onclick/onClick event without success. Nothing happens or I got error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name.

When I'm putting break point inside map function and calling `value()` it is returning values as expected.

I would like to get buttons with name equal to specific key and with onClick event which will trigger function passed as value in object above. What is important, I can't use jQuery neither other dom supporting libraries.

Comment: Have you considered attaching the event listeners using Javascript instead of an inline attribute (which are considered to be pretty poor practice)?

Comment: When button has onclick="()=> console.log('a')" set. When you click button it just unwraps function and don't call console.log('a'). In order to call console.log('a') you would have to either `addEventListener` as @CertainPerformance said or wrap it as onclick="(()=> console.log('a'))()". https://jsfiddle.net/rw5afyg1/3/

Comment: Thanks to yours suggestions I got this working solution:
`<button onclick="(${value})()">${key}</button>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is difficult? Unless you use the `this` keyword or use a `'string'` of some kind the first parameter in these scenarios *are* going to be the `event` object. As a good practice I no longer use `e` (`event` only now) as I use `e` as a variable for other practices.

**JavaScript**

```
function function_name(event) {console.log(event);}
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="function_name(event);">test</button>
```

I have yet to find a worthwhile way of standardizing `addEventListener` so while a lot of people frown on using event attributes (`onclick=""`) you need to pick your battles by making *some* reasonable presumptions.